# Who was told what about the loss of the Primarchs?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

The Primarchs were removed from the Emperor by Chaos when they were babies, over time each Primarch was rediscovered and reunited with the great crusade, each return triggering a large celebration not just in the legion but in the Imperium at large.

If the Emperor wanted to keep the presence of chaos hidden from the Imperium what where the people told about the loss of the Primarchs. They must have been told something if they knew to celebrate that his sons had been found?

Comment: That's a good point... I don't think GW ever covers that blip, but I suppose it could be explained away by saying that the incubators somehow tapped into the Warp (maybe for power or something) and a miscalculation/error caused portals to open up and suck them in... That seems like a reasonable excuse I think!

Comment: An error? By the Emperor? Unthinkable.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of the Emperor, Malcador, Valdor(and possibly the legio custodes) and Amar astarte No one knew about the disappearance of the Primarchs. Until the first deployment the high lords of that time didn't even know about the astrates project. Any info of the gene-stock/crafting and stuff like that was highly confidential.

Comment: If you read Valdor, one of the primarch series of books, he does tell a high lord about the loss of the primarchs and htis recording makes its way off terra, If no one knew the primarchs where lost then why was there great celebration when a primarch was found?